# Losing return Type information When Mono flatmap collecting

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I wrote code like below using Reactor

```
    private Mono<Map<String, A>> resolve(Mono<Map<String, List<B>>> bMapMono) {
        return bMapMono.flatMap(bMap -> bMap.entrySet().stream()
                                                     .map(entry -> toAfunc(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                                                     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                                     .collect(Collectors.<A, String, A>toMap(x -> x.getStringKey(), Function.identity())));
    }
```

But it display error in compiler intellij

like this

```
Required type: Mono <Map<String, A>> 
Provided: Mono <Object>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use map instead of flatMap

Comment: @Alex The result is the same with the map

Comment: also not sure why you need `<A, String, A>`. try to remove it

Comment: what toAfunc(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()) does? share the code

Comment: @Alex if remove ```<A, String, A>``` can't show type in ```toMap```, x is inferenced object.

Comment: @kerbermeister ```toAfunc(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())```just business logic, transform to A class.

Comment: you can also remove the filter as Null is not allowed in reactive streams, you will never have null in the stream, reactor will throw a NullPointerException

Comment: @Toerktumlare the filter is applied to a non-reactive stream within the flatMap, so a null is possible.

Comment: Ah my misstake! Carry on, nothing to see here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error in IntelliJ. It seems as though the lambda in your Mono::flatMap is returning a Map, while what you want to return is a Mono. While you could solve the issue by wrapping the lambda result in a mono, you might want to consider using the reactor-methods which support what you might be trying to achieve with your stream. Consider the following:

```
        return bMapMono.flatMapIterable(Map::entrySet)
                .mapNotNull(entry -> toAfunc(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getStringKey, Function.identity()));
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems like the compiler is unable to infer the correct type for the result of the Collectors.toMap operation. To solve this issue, you can explicitly specify the type of the returned map

```
private Mono<Map<String, A>> resolve(Mono<Map<String, List<B>>> bMapMono) {
    return bMapMono.flatMap(bMap -> bMap.entrySet().stream()
                                                 .map(entry -> toAfunc(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                                                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getStringKey(), Function.identity(), (a, b) -> a, HashMap::new)));
}
```

In this code, HashMap::new is used to create a new instance of a HashMap, which is used as the result of the Collectors.toMap operation.

This should resolve the issue and allow the compiler to correctly infer the type of the returned Mono.